# PHP: unusual table from array

Tags: php, arrays

Suppose that you have an array like this one:

```
Array([0] => Array([first_name] => Stack [last_name] => Overflow)
      [1] => Array([first_name] => Andrew [last_name] => Oliveira)
     );
```

It is easy to populate a table on the following way:

```
 <th>first name</th>
   <th>last name</th>
<? foreach($info as $key => $data) { ?>
 <tr>
   <td><?= $data['first_name'] ?> </td>
   <td><?= $data['last_name'] ?> </td>
 <tr>
 <? } ?>
```

The above produces a table like this:

```
first name || last name
========================
Stack-------|| Overflow
========================
Andrew----|| Oliveira
========================
```

And so on... But how would you do to do a table like this, given the same array:

```
person 0 || person 1
========================
Stack-----|| Andrew
========================
Overflow|| Oliveira
========================
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
<?php
// create line with "Person X"
echo '<tr>';
$s = sizeof ($info);
for ($i=0;$i<$s;++$i) {
  echo '<td>Person '.$i.'</td>';
}
echo '</tr><tr>';

// create line with first name
foreach ($info as $data) {
  echo '<td>'.$data['first_name'].'</td>';
}
echo '</tr><tr>';

// create line with last name
foreach ($info as $data) {
  echo '<td>'.$data['last_name'].'</td>';
}
echo '</tr>';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, very easy in fact, but use this method:

```
<?php $COUNT_INFO=count($info); ?>
<th>first name</th>
    <th>last name</th>
    <tr>
        <? for($i=0; $i<$COUNT_INFO; $i++) { ?>
        <td><?= $info[$i]['first_name'] ?> </td>
        <? } ?>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <? for($i=0; $i<$COUNT_INFO; $i++) { ?>
        <td><?= $info[$i]['last_name'] ?> </td>
        <? } ?>
    <tr>
```

Comment: This code snippet will output the same as the OP, how does it help?

Comment: ah i see you modified the question, hang on i'll refix my code

Comment: Basically my code is another variation of JercSi's so use the one you like most :)

Comment: @Dany Khalife one info: never put count or sizeof into the loop. Because loop will execute 100+% longer then, if you put $count outside of the loop.

Comment: true! i left that part out, will modify that :)

Answer (score 0):

Make two arrays, one for first names and another for last names. After that, use `foreach` to loop through them and concatenate the first and the second line of your table.

```
foreach($array as $i=>$data){
    $headers .= "<th>Person $i</th>";
    $first_names .= "<td>".$data["first_name"]."</td>";
    $last_names .= "<td>".$data["first_name"]."</td>";
}

echo "<table>
         <tr>$headers</tr>
         <tr>$first_names</tr>
         <tr>$last_names</tr>
      </table>";
```

There you go! Just one loop! :)

Answer (score 0):

The answer of @Vitor42 is ok, but if you want something more generic and you are sure that the data is always complete try with:

```
<table>
<?php
$info = array(
    array('first_name'=>'Stack','last_name'=>'Overflow'),
    array('first_name'=>'Andrew','last_name'=>'Oliveira')
);
$sHtmlHead = '<tr>';
$arrHtmlBodies = array();
$nSize = sizeOf($info);

for($i=0;$i<$nSize;$i++){
    $sHtmlHead .= '<th>Person '.$i.'</th>';
    $arrTemp = $info[$i];
    $j = 0;
    foreach($arrTemp as $data){
        if(!isset($arrHtmlBodies[$j])) $arrHtmlBodies[$j] = '<tr>';
        $arrHtmlBodies[$j] .= '<td>'.$data.'</td>';
        if($i==($nSize-1)) $arrHtmlBodies[$j] .= '</tr>';
        $j++;
    }
} 
echo $sHtmlHead; ?></tr>
<?php
echo implode('',$arrHtmlBodies); ?></tr>
</table>
```

If you are not sure that the data is complete try with:

```
<table>
<?php
$info = array(
    array('first_name'=>'Stack','last_name'=>'Overflow'),
    array('first_name'=>'Andrew','last_name'=>'Oliveira'),
    array('first_name'=>'Eli'),
    array('last_name'=>'Astocaza')
);
$sHtmlHead = '<tr>';
$arrHtmlBodies = array();
$nSize = sizeOf($info);
$arrKeys = array_keys($info['0']);
$nSizeKeys = sizeOf($arrKeys);
for($i=0;$i<$nSize;$i++){
    $sHtmlHead .= '<th>Person '.$i.'</th>';
    $arrTemp = $info[$i];
    $j = 0;
    for($j=0;$j<$nSizeKeys;$j++){
        if(!isset($arrHtmlBodies[$j])) $arrHtmlBodies[$j] = '<tr>';
        $arrHtmlBodies[$j] .= '<td>'.$info[$i][$arrKeys[$j]].'</td>';
        if($i==($nSize-1)) $arrHtmlBodies[$j] .= '</tr>';
    }
} 
echo $sHtmlHead; ?></tr>
<?php
echo implode('',$arrHtmlBodies); ?></tr>
</table>
```